# Authorization header not added in Angular

Tags: angular, ngrx

I'm using angular to build a web app. My app is using jwt token for authentification. So for all outgouing request I have defined an interceptor to add the authorization header. The code is as follow :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AuthenticateService } from '../service/authenticate.service';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private authenticateService: AuthenticateService) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + this.authenticateService.getJwtToken()
      }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

My authenticateService is as follow :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { SignUpUser } from '../model/signUpUser.model';
import { environment } from './../../../environments/environment';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticateService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  storeJwtToken(token: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('Authorization', token);
  }

  getJwtToken() {
    return localStorage.getItem('Authorization');
  }

  deleteJwtToken() {
    localStorage.removeItem('Authorization');
  }
}
```

In my app.module I have added the interceptot to the providers array as follow :

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TokenInterceptor } from './account/interceptor/token.interceptor';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: TokenInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    AuthenticateService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm using ngrx to manage my state application so the request to the server is done in a effect as follow 
:

```
@Injectable()
export class LibraryEffects {

constructor(private libraryService: LibraryService,
              private userService: UserService,
              private actions$: Actions,
              private router: Router) { }

  @Effect()
  loadLibraries$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(libraryActions.LibraryActionTypes.LoadShortLibraries),
    mergeMap(action =>
      this.libraryService.getAllByUser().pipe(
        map(libraries => (new libraryActions.LoadSuccesShortLibraries(libraries))),
        catchError(err => of(new libraryActions.LoadFailShortLibraries(err)))
      )
    )
  );
}
```

And the service that do the request is the following :

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LibraryService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthenticateService) { }

  getAllByUser(): Observable<ShortLibrary[]> {
    return this.http.get<ShortLibrary[]>(
      environment.apiUrl + '/media/users/' + this.authService.getUserId() + '/libraries')
      // {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${this.authService.getJwtToken()}`)})
      .pipe(map((res: any) => res.content as ShortLibrary[]));
  }
}
```

I end up with a request which is missing the authorization header and I can't understand why. If I put a console.log in the interceptor I got a log in the console so it seems my interceptor is well registered and called when the request is made but the authorization header is not set.

Any idea why ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try 'headers' instead of 'setHeaders' in request.clone

Comment: add `deps: [AuthenticateService]` below your multi: true in http interceptors module providers. Also; what does `getJwtToken()` do?

Comment: AuthenticateService is already added to my providers array. I edited the post. getJwtToken retrieve the jwt token from the local storage. Also If i replace setHeaders by headers I have an error

Comment: please share your auth service also

Comment: I have just done it

Comment: Other than your use of the Library service, i see no differences with the way it works for me. If i do this setHeaders: { Test: 'test' } in the interceptor instead, the Test header shows in the network request tab. there are two requests every time, one without the added header then one with

Comment: Do you have more than one `HttpClientModule` import in your project ?

Comment: Indeed I imported `HttpClientModule` in app.module and library.module. I removed it from library.module and now it's working. If you post your answer with I a bit of exlanation I will accept it